# Super basic jquery gallery - trouble getting prev button working

Tags: jquery, gallery

I'm still finding my way with jQuery and have a basic gallery setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/0868wvc5/

So far so good except the previous button doesn't work - here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
// next and previous buttons
$('.gallery-nav a').click(function() {

  var button = $(this).attr('class');
  var currentItem = $('.gallery-item.active');
  var next;

  if (button == 'gallery-nav-prev') {
    next = ($('.gallery-item.active').prev().length > 0) ?
    $('.gallery-item.active').prev() :
    $('.gallery-item:last-child');
  } else {
    next = ($('.gallery-item.active').next().length > 0) ?
    $('.gallery-item.active').next() :
    $('.gallery-item:first-child');
  }

  next.css('z-index', 200).show();

  currentItem.fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', 100).removeClass('active');
    next.css('z-index', 300).addClass('active');
  });

  return false; // stop page jumping to top when buttons are clicked
});
```

I suspect I'm missing something basic so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (button == 'gallery-button gallery-nav-prev') {
```

This will fix it. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0868wvc5/1/

Simple, jQuery attr('class') value is different. You have multiple classes there.